# Should entities or dtos be shared between client and microservices?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, architecture, monorepo

I have monorepo that contains our backend projects (microservices) and frontend projects (backoffice and client).

If I want to make an API call from the frontend to the backend, is that ok to share the DTOs in some shared library?

What is the best practice in that case?

Thanks!